# CSS for applying a horizontal fading transparency animation to a png image

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-selectors, css-animations

I'm trying to find the right classes or code to apply an animated transparency that swipes from left to right over a png graphic that essentially reveals the image from left to right, then fades out to completely transparent and then fades back in for a full reveal. I haven't found any examples to demo what I'm looking for so forgive my explanation if you can't visualise it.

Also, my knowledge of CSS, HTML, JS is very basic as I only started learning them a few months ago.

The image sequence below is what I'm trying to achieve in an animation format.

Many thanks in advance.

[dotted swish](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GxWlk.png)

Comment: Please include the code that you tried in your question. There are so many tutorials about creating animations, such as https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_animations.asp

Comment: Thanks for replying @Yogi. The blue background isn't necessary as its the white that is needed. I have a separate image of the white dots as a png with a transparent background. Blue is just for illustration purposes.

Comment: Thanks for replying @Kokodoko. I haven't tried any code as yet, as I didn't know what classes to be calling. I shall check out the link you sent. Much appreciated.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.